# Button get data from the combobox -- Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, combobox

I am trying to change the button into a combo box. the original code is as below

```
private void btnSign_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        stopWatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        record = true;
        redOrGreen = new Bgr(Color.LightGreen);

        if (sender == btnSign1)
            recordSign = 1;
        else if (sender == btnSign2)
            recordSign = 2;
        else if (sender == btnSign3)
            recordSign = 3;
        else if (sender == btnSign4)
            recordSign = 4;
        else if (sender == btnSign5)
            recordSign = 5;
        else
            recordSign = 6;
    }
```

at the if-else statement there is the button that i originally have and i want to replace those btnSign to a combo box.

any solution?

Comment: change the if tests to check the selected index.  of course if there are no more button, the code has to move to the SelectedIndexChanged event

Comment: What do you mean by _Visual Studio button_ ? I guess it is `WPF` button?

Comment: i still need a single button to execute the code. so any idea how do it? can help me to edit it or give me a roughly idea how to do so?

Comment: same basic thing - evaluate the cbo.selectedindex  instead of the various button objects

Comment: if(sender == cbo.selectedindex)??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Populate the combobox with a list of items and use the selected item property to drive your logic. Here is an example:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
  public class RecordSign
  {
    public int recordSign { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
  }

  public partial class Form1 : Form
  {
    int recordSign = 0;

    public Form1()
    {
      InitializeComponent();

      comboBox1.Items.Add(new RecordSign() { recordSign = 1, Description = "Record Sign 1" });
      comboBox1.Items.Add(new RecordSign() { recordSign = 2, Description = "Record Sign 2" });
      comboBox1.Items.Add(new RecordSign() { recordSign = 3, Description = "Record Sign 3" });
      comboBox1.Items.Add(new RecordSign() { recordSign = 4, Description = "Record Sign 4" });
      comboBox1.Items.Add(new RecordSign() { recordSign = 5, Description = "Record Sign 5" });
      comboBox1.Items.Add(new RecordSign() { recordSign = 6, Description = "Record Sign 6" });

      //Show the user-friendly text in the combobox
      comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Description";

      //Use the underlying value of the selected object for code logic
      comboBox1.ValueMember = "recordSign";

    }

    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      //SelectedValue is an [object] so cast it to the type you need.
      var theRecordSign = comboBox1.SelectedItem as RecordSign;

      label1.Text = string.Format(
        "The chosen item is {0}, and its value is {1}.",
        theRecordSign.Description, theRecordSign.recordSign);

      recordSign = theRecordSign.recordSign;

    }
  }
}
```